# Why is 3D projection in OpenGL working, but leaving a trail behind?

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, glsl

I just did some math from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Mathematical_formula) for 3D projection because I noticed they were simple, library not needed. It does work but, the cube leaves a trail behind as it moves. Note that the cube doesn't actually move, I am actually changing the camera position which makes he cube look like it's moving.

There's no need to point out 100 bad practices that I am doing, I'm aware, this is just supposed to be be a quick test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "utils.h"
#include "keys.h"

char p = 1;

typedef struct Vec3 {
float x;
float y;
float z;
} Vec3;

void Mat_iden(float *m, Uint32 s) {
Uint32 i = 0;
Uint32 unt = s + 1;
while (i < s) {
    m[unt * i] = 1;
    i++;
}
}

float one[3][3];
float two[3][3];
float three[3][3];

int main() {
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 5);

SDL_Window *w = SDL_CreateWindow("Snapdoop", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
SDL_GLContext c = SDL_GL_CreateContext(w);

gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)SDL_GL_GetProcAddress);

Mat_iden(one[0], 3);
Mat_iden(two[0], 3);
Mat_iden(three[0], 3);

Shader s[2];

s[0] = Shade("/home/shambhav/eclipse-workspace/Snadoop/src/vs.glsl");
s[1] = Shade("/home/shambhav/eclipse-workspace/Snadoop/src/fs.glsl");
Shade_comp(&s[0], GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
Shade_comp(&s[1], GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
Program sp;
Prog_attach(&sp, s, 2);
printf("VS: %s\n", s[0].info);
printf("FS: %s\n", s[1].info);
printf("SP: %s\n", sp.info);
glDeleteShader(s[0].c);
glDeleteShader(s[1].c);

float v[48] = {
        //Front
        0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        -0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        -0.25, -0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        0.25, -0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        //Back
        0.25, 0.25, -0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        -0.25, 0.25, -0.25, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        0.25, -0.25, -0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
};
unsigned int i[36] = {
        //Front
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0,
        //Right
        0, 3, 7,
        7, 4, 0,
        //Left
        1, 2, 6,
        6, 5, 2,
        //Back
        4, 5, 6,
        6, 7, 4,
        //Up
        0, 1, 5,
        5, 4, 0,
        //Down
        3, 7, 2,
        2, 6, 7
};

GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(v), v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(i), i, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (void *)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (void *)(sizeof(float) * 3));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

Vec3 cam = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
Vec3 theta = {0, 0, 0};

Key k = (const Key){ 0 };
printf("%d\n", k.alpha[9]);

SDL_Event e;
while (p) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
        switch (e.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            p = 0;
            break;

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            *key(&k, e.key.keysym.sym) = 1;
            break;

        case SDL_KEYUP:
            *key(&k, e.key.keysym.sym) = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (*key(&k, SDLK_RIGHT)) {
        cam.x += 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, SDLK_LEFT)) {
        cam.x -= 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, SDLK_UP)) {
        cam.y += 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, SDLK_DOWN)) {
        cam.y -= 0.01;
    }

    if (*key(&k, 'w')) {
        theta.y += 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, 's')) {
        theta.y -= 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, 'a')) {
        theta.x -= 0.01;
    }
    if  (*key(&k, 'd')) {
        theta.x += 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, 'z')) {
        theta.z -= 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, 'x')) {
        theta.z += 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, 'n')) {
        cam.z += 0.01;
    }
    if (*key(&k, 'm')) {
        cam.z -= 0.01;
    }

    one[1][1] = cos(theta.x);
    one[1][2] = sin(theta.x);
    one[2][1] = -sin(theta.x);
    one[2][2] = cos(theta.x);

    two[0][0] = cos(theta.y);
    two[0][2] = -sin(theta.y);
    two[2][0] = sin(theta.y);
    two[2][2] = cos(theta.y);

    three[0][0] = cos(theta.z);
    three[0][1] = sin(theta.z);
    three[1][0] = -sin(theta.z);
    three[1][1] = cos(theta.z);

    glUseProgram(sp.p);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(2, 1, GL_FALSE, one[0]);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(3, 1, GL_FALSE, two[0]);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(4, 1, GL_FALSE, three[0]);
    glUniform3f(5, cam.x, cam.y, cam.z);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(w);
}

glDeleteProgram(sp.p);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

SDL_GL_DeleteContext(c);
SDL_DestroyWindow(w);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

Vertex Shader(vs.glsl):

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 tcol;
layout (location = 2) uniform mat3 x;
layout (location = 3) uniform mat3 y;
layout (location = 4) uniform mat3 z;
layout (location = 5) uniform vec3 c;

out vec3 col;

void main() {
vec3 d = x * y * z * (pos - c);
gl_Position.x = d.x / d.z;
gl_Position.y = d.y / d.z;
gl_Position.z = 0.0;
gl_Position.w = 1.0;
col = tcol;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 450 core

out vec4 color;

in vec3 col;

void main() {
color = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

I think that keys.h and utils.h should not be here as they are not relevant to OpenGL. And this is a Minimum Reproducible Example as the only extra parts(keys.h and utils.h) are required for managing key data and loading shaders respectively.

Some keys in my code may be inverted, it's just bad code in all ways... Sorry for that.

[image: Example of the trail]

This is an image I have taken after moving the cube(or the camera perspective to be accurate). One major thing to note is that it seems to be working perfectly other than the trail.

Comment: Facepalm?  I see no [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml) of the `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` You only cleared the depth buffer.  You can _or_ them together `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: @Wyck Does doing glClear(ANYTHING) clear that thing from the screen?

Comment: Was the [documentation for glClear](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml) not clear about what it does? ;)

Comment: @Wyck No, it was not clear, don't know why I'm not understanding this properly, but I'm not. I have no idea why I'm not understanding a simple documentation when I'm used to reading dry Maths at Wikipedia. I thought doing `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` cleared the depth functionality from the current frame, exact opposite now I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clear the color buffer as well:

<s>`glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`</s>

```cpp
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

[`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) clears the specified buffers. The buffers are specified with a bit mask. `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` indicates to clear the buffers currently enabled for color writing.

Comment: Beat me to it -- was just writing this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what that does?

Comment: @ShambhavGautam [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) clears the specified buffers. The buffers are specified with a bit mask. `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` indicates to clear the buffer currently enabled for color writing

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need to change:

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

...to...

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

#### More details

Comments have asked for more elaboration, so I'll elaborate.

When you say `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` it clears out the pixel values in the Z-Buffer (depth buffer).  When you say `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` it clears out the RGBA channels of the pixels in the color buffer (sets them to the glClearColor).  If you say `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` it clears both the Z-Buffer and the color buffer at the same time.  *That's what you want to do.*  You want to start each frame with a fresh black background and draw your content for that frame over top of it.

Think of it like setting each pixel to black and setting the depth value to zero.    Actually, it will set the color buffer to the color specified by `glClearColor` and will set the depth value to the value specified by `glClearDepth`.

In your comment you said that you thought it "clears the functionality".  That's not what `glClear` does.  ***If*** you wanted to enable or disable writing to the depth buffer completely, you could do so with with `glDepthMask`.  This function lets you completely disable writes to the depth buffer, potentially while still writing color values to the color buffer.  There is a similar function called `glColorMask` that lets you select which channels of the color buffer (red, green, blue, and/or alpha) you want to write to as well.  In this way you could potentially do interesting things like rendering only green, or even doing a special effect where you do a render pass in which you render only depth values and *not* color values (perhaps in preparation for knocking out a special effect to be applied in a subsequent pass.)  `glClear`, conversely, actually sets the values in the pixels of the color buffer or depth buffer.

In the code you posted, you're only doing `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`, which is only clearing the depth buffer, but not the color buffer.  This essentially leaves all the paint on the canvas from last frame you drew, so leftover images from previous frames remain visible on the screen.  You should be clearing both buffers.

> Because you only draw your colorful square each frame, you draw a new square over top of whatever was in the buffer from last time.  If you're double-buffering (common in full-screen graphics modes, but not windowed graphics modes), you may find that you're drawing over top of a frame from two-frames-ago, which may produce a strobing/flashing marquee effect.

The argument to `glClear` is called a *bitmask*.  It uses each bit of the mask like a checkbox to select whether a particular kind of buffer should be cleared.  Specifying `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` will logically *OR* the bits together creating a number with both bits set -- which is like checking both checkboxes, saying, "yes, please clear the depth buffer, and yes also clear the color buffer".

There can be up to four different kinds of buffers, not just color and depth. The four mask fields are `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`, `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`, `GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT`, and `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT`.  Each one of these is a bit-field value, a number with a single binary bit set, which can be logically OR'ed together like 4 individual checkboxes.  In your application your render target may not have an accumulator buffer or a stencil buffer.  Some render targets don't even make use of a depth buffer.  It's totally up to how you created your render buffer originally.  In your case it looks like you have a buffer with color and depth.  So when it comes time to clear the buffer, in preparation for rendering the frame, you'll want to make sure you *check both boxes*, effectively asking for both the color and depth components of your buffers to be cleared.  Do so by passing `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` as the argument to `glClear`.

The use of bit-fields here is so exemplary, that `glClear` is actually used on the Wikipedia page for [Mask_(computing) - Uses of bitmasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)#Uses_of_bitmasks) to explain how bitmasks can be used!